# Grouping element array depend key checking?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array :

```
Array
    (
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [type] => type1
            [aa] => 1.00
            [bb] => 0.00
            [cc] => 1.00
            [group] => new
        ),
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [type] => type2
            [aa] => 1.00
            [bb] => 0.00
            [cc] => 1.00
            [group] => new
        ),
    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 4521081
            [type] => type3
            [aa] => 1.00
            [bb] => 0.00
            [cc] => 1.00
            [group] => old
        )
);
```

How can I group the above array base key checking.result look some thing like this:

```
Array(
    'new'=>array(
        'type1'=>array(
                    [id] => 0
                    [aa] => 1.00
                    [bb] => 0.00
                    [cc] => 1.00
                    ),
        'type2'=>array(
                        [aa] => 1.00
                        [bb] => 0.00
                        [cc] => 1.00
                        )
    ),
    'old'=>array(
             'type3'=>array(
                        [aa] => 1.00
                        [bb] => 0.00
                        [cc] => 1.00
                        )
            )
);
```

Comment: Have you tried using `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
$res    = array();
foreach($your_array as $val){
   $res[$val['group']][$val['type']]['id']  = $val['id'];
   $res[$val['group']][$val['type']]['aa']  = $val['aa'];
   $res[$val['group']][$val['type']]['bb']  = $val['bb'];
   $res[$val['group']][$val['type']]['cc']  = $val['cc'];
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach( $array as $each )
{
   $tmp = $each;
   unset( $tmp['group'],$tmp['type'] );
   $output[$each['group']][$each['type']] = $tmp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I do:

```
foreach($array as $each)
{
  $output[$each['group']] = $each;
}
```

It has more size, but looks nice and sometime you will need group too.